# JS handling objects with long keys

Tags: javascript

I have a question about how JS handles cases likes this.

Ley's say you have an empty object:

```
var object = {};
```

And an XML in memory as an string:

```
var xml = '<node1><node2>blah blah....';
```

Now you want to associate that XML with some information, so you could do something like:

```
object[xml] = 'extra info';
```

Imagine you have several more XMLs, so that object will have N properties, with potentially long strings as keys, and other objects as values.

The questions are how JS handles the access to these properties by keys (this means knowing the XML), and how performant is it. Is it just an iteration over the keys comparing the strings or there is something else happening?

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, this is not something I want to do, but something that a library I use (Moustache.js) is doing, as you can see [here](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L441-L453). I want to know how this affects the performance of my application.

Comment: It's probably just a hashmap that stores keys and values so they can be looked up again. Using a string of XML as a key does seem like a **horrible** idea regardless of how long that string is, or anything else really.

Comment: It's not something I would like to do, but found [this](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L441-L453) on the code of Moustache.js, and I've been wondering since then.

Answer (score 2):

You could hash the XML every time you need to add a key or look up a value. This would reduce the memory requirement, but would increase processing time when doing look-ups.

```
var xml = '<node1><node2>blah blah....';
object[hash(xml)] = 'extra info';

var info = object[hash(xml)];
```

If you need to be able to pull the XML out again, for example by looping over the keys, you could use a serialization technique to decrease the size instead.

```
var xml = '<node1><node2>blah blah....';
object[serialize(xml)] = 'extra info';

for (var key in object) {
  var originalXml = deserialize(key);
  var info = object[key];
}
```

Comment: Hi Brandon. I edited the post clarifying that the question is about the impact of this code on my application since it is on a library I use. But thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: What do you mean? I see it's using the plain XMLs as keys